# Merging n number of list into a Map based on a value in List

Tags: java, collections

I have the following objects in an `ArrayList` and a value in this object is illustrated as the numbers at the beginning, which are `Id` of something.

[image]

I need to create a `Map` object, whose key should be the id of objects and whose values should be the objects with id. At the end of the day, I would like to have a Map something like that.

[image]

I have already solved this problem with two for loops and lots of `if` statements but it seems very ugly to me.

Any cleaner solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get the first picture: what kind of list are you talking about? You can't have a list where the the **first** element is an ID; and the other elements are something else. Then: maps have one value per key. So, if you really want to have multiple entries, then you need a `Map<Id, List<whatever>>`.

Comment: @GhostCat This is just an illustration. This is a quite normal list and a value in an object, which the list holds, is illustrated as an Id. We say, it is just a value in the object, which the list holds.

Comment: You need to show some code, and give a specific problem about it. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: @GhostCat I editted my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, List<Foo>> result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to fit the question edit, it is as simple as this:

```java
ArrayList<Element> list = ...;
HashMap<Integer, List<Element>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Element>>();

for(Element e : list) {
    ArrayList<Element> auxList;
    if(map.contains(e.getId()) {
        auxList = map.get(e.getId());
    } else {
        auxList = new ArrayList<Element>();
        map.put(e.getId(), auxList);
    }
    auxList.add(e);
}
```

Just iterate over the starting list and add the elements to the map. If the map already contains the id, add it to the list. If not, create a new list.

Comment: I have editted my question. I think it is clearer now.

Comment: @AdInfinitum I edited my answer consequently. Hope it helps.